# Moving blazor components to a shared components project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I'm trying to have my blazor server to blazor wasm. we a good part of the project developed already but we want to move anyway. There is where the doubt comes. I created a project of components to be able to share them, but I'm trying to move the pages as well there, and now the routing is picking up nothing and got what is in the index and nothing more.
how I do make my app aware that it should render pages from a project under .components (the blazor components library) and not what is under .cliente (the blazor server project)

Comment: You can run your SPA in both Server and WASM Modes if you wish - Search for "Blazor AllInOne" and you should find links to an article of mine that describes how to run both Server and WASM on the same site.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have structure with these 3 projects:

- `ClientWasm` -> The project where is your index page and where you want to use your components
- `Components` -> Project with components (of type `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">`)
- `ClientServer` -> Old Blazor server project

Now. If you want to use component in `ClientWasm` that is located in `Components` you have to add reference to Components in `ClientWasm`

If you have pages with routes (in `Components`) you need to add additional Assemblies in `ClientWasm`:

```
@*App.razor in ClientWasm project*@
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly"
            AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Components.SomePage).Assembly}">
```

Comment: where I'm having issues is that I do have some pages with routes in the components project. and its not been picked, is there a way to make that work?

Comment: Sorry, the code was wrong (fixe now). You have to add additional assemblies from component projects of course. This will make the pages from Components project work.